# unit testing a MixIn class which is accessing another class method in one of its methods

Tags: python, design-patterns

I have two Mixin classes. One of the methods in a Mixin class is calling a method from another class. Everything works fine when I create a subclass by inheriting from these two Mixins.

```
class FirstMixin(object):
    def method(self):
         some logic here  
         self.method_of_sub_class()

class SecondMixin(object):
    def method_of_sub_class()
        pass

class BaseClass(SecondMixin, FirstMixin):
    pass
```

When I write unit test cases for FirstMixin class, its getting failed because of the `method_of_sub_class` call. How can I write unit test cases for the first MixIn class which is calling a method from another class?

Comment: Your design is flawed. Calling `method_of_subclass` from `FirstMixin.method` means that `FirstMixin` is too tightly coupled with `SecondMixin`.

Comment: @chepner, Thanks for comments. I can explain the reason behind this design, I am keeping this Subclass as a base class for other classes. I can add First and Second Mixin methods to the Subclass and solve the issue but I don't need the methods of First and Second most of the time. I think I should rename the subclass name to base class. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Perhaps `FirstMixin` should inherit from `SecondMixin`? Even if your use-case for the mix-ins always uses them together, they should still be designed as if each could be used alone.

Comment: At least one of your mix-ins doesn't really seem like a mix-in, but the base for `BaseClass`.

Answer (score 2):

@chepner is correct; you are having trouble with your unittesting because your class is not fully encapsulated. FirstMixin should only be calling methods that are available to it directly. It's hard to say without knowing the larger architecture of your program, but one solution could be to add a passthrough `method_of_subclass` to `FirstMixin` to act as an abstract method, although this will lead to a rather complicated design. A better idea might be to ask yourself why you need two separate mixins if FirstMixin needs to call methods defined in SecondMixin

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Can I have a dummy class in the unittest class to test the functionalities together something like below
class dummy(FirstMxin, MainClass):
    pass

Comment: As far as I read, mixins _can_ assume that the classes they will be mixed-in with derive from a certain base class. So they can use the attributes of that class. This would basically be the difference between a mixin and normal composition/inheritance. Or is this concept wrong?